# How does LLDB find inlined functions?

Tags: c++, macos, symbols, lldb

When setting a breakpoint by specifying a Symbol Name, lldb not only resolves that symbol, but also finds where the function has been used inlined. How is that possible?

```
1: name = 'my_func', locations = 4, resolved = 1, hit count = 1
  1.1: where = kernel.development`my_func + 6 at task.c:17, address = 0xxxx, resolved, hit count = 0 
  1.2: where = kernel.development`func_foo + 119 [inlined] my_func at task.c:22, address = 0xxxx, unresolved, hit count = 0  Options: disabled 
  1.3: where = kernel.development`func_bar + 95 [inlined] my_func at task.c:65, address = 0xxxx, unresolved, hit count = 1  Options: disabled
```

Looking at LLDB's source, I could only find where it checked if a certain block is inlined: `//source/API/SBBlock.cpp`

```cpp
bool SBBlock::IsInlined() const {
  LLDB_RECORD_METHOD_CONST_NO_ARGS(bool, SBBlock, IsInlined);

  if (m_opaque_ptr)
    return m_opaque_ptr->GetInlinedFunctionInfo() != nullptr;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An LLDB testcase in [`split-dwarf-inlining.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/lldb/test/Shell/SymbolFile/DWARF/split-dwarf-inlining.cpp) confirms that [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information is used to find inline functions.

```
// RUN: %clangxx -target x86_64-pc-linux -gsplit-dwarf -fsplit-dwarf-inlining \
// RUN:   -c %s -o %t
// RUN: %lldb %t -o "breakpoint set -n foo" -b | FileCheck %s

// CHECK: Breakpoint 1: 2 locations

__attribute__((always_inline)) int foo(int x) { return x; }
int bar(int x) { return foo(x); }
```

Comment: That would make sense, if I compiled it myself and let the compile produce the dwarf file, but it in this case its the kernel

Comment: I'm not sure what information you are asking for.  lldb only supports two debug info formats, DWARF & PDF (the windows debugging format).  The fact that you are seeing any line table information at all means that you your kernel does have debug information, and if lldb is reading it successfully, it's pretty certain it is DWARF.  If you want to know more about how DWARF encodes line tables & inlined information, the standard is here: http://dwarfstd.org/Dwarf5Std.php, section 3.3.8 is on the representation of inlined routines.

Comment: Agreed, although I've never heard of PDF (as a debugging format). PDB perhaps?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning [the ELF spec](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf) as well. I don't have kernel compilation experience; however, it is likely that the DWARF information is in a `.debug` section (or similar) of the compiled kernel, i.e. the same file.

Answer (score 0):

If you run dwarfinfo on an executable it'll show "nested" inline methods, so that's how it finds it.

Where it actually finds it:

GetBlock:
Gets the deepest block that contains the frame PC.

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/d01083a850f577b85501a0902b52fd0930de72c7/include/lldb/API/SBFrame.h#L60

deepest block I believe refers to the inline methods being "nested."

Then it can call getInlinedParent or getParent on that "lowest block" to generate the output.  Something like that...